# Show div if item contains same text as link text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a blog that outputs posts from multiple categories and want to be able to filter them based on category while staying on the page. For instance, if I click Tag 2 I want all posts to show up with Tag 2. Since there isn't an easy way to do this in the CMS I figured I would add another field to the post that displays the category, and use jQuery to see if there's a match and return the results.

- By default I'd like to display all posts
- After clicking a "filter" (from tr-nav) I'd like to only show posts from that category (from tr-category).
- If tr-title and tr-category are the same then only those posts should show

Does anyone know of an easy way to handle this?

I've found the following snippet which auto sorts based on category, but I want this to happen on click. I've tried messing with this but can't get anything to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $('.tr-wrap .tr-category').length; i++) {
    var name = $('.tr-wrap .tr-category').eq( i );
    for (var d = 0; d < $('.tr-title').length; d++) {
        var title = $('.tr-title').eq( d );
      if ( title.text() == name.text()  ) {
            var parent = name.closest('.tr-item');
          var titleContain = title.closest('.tr-contain').find('.tr-list');
            parent.clone(true, true).appendTo( titleContain );
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tr-nav">
  <a href="#"><div class="tr-title">All</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="tr-title">Tag 1</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="tr-title">Tag 2</div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="tr-title">Tag 3</div></a>
</div>

<div class="tr-wrap">
  <div class="tr-list">
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-item">
      <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
      <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your posts by adding the `tag name` as a class to each post. I hope this will help you

```js
        function filterPosts(tag) {
            const postsList = document.querySelectorAll('.tr-item');
            if (tag === 'all') {
                postsList.forEach(post => {
                    post.classList.remove('hidden');
                });
            } else {
                postsList.forEach(post => {
                    if (post.classList.contains(tag)) {
                        post.classList.remove('hidden');
                    } else {
                        post.classList.add('hidden');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="tr-nav">
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts('all')">
            <div class="tr-title ">All</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts('tag-1')">
            <div class="tr-title">Tag 1</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts('tag-2')">
            <div class="tr-title">Tag 2</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts('tag-3')">
            <div class="tr-title ">Tag 3</div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tr-wrap">
        <div class="tr-list">
            <div class="tr-item tag-3">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item tag-2">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item tag-3">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item  tag-1">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item tag-2">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item tag-3">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this JavaScript code without adding any classes, but you should make sure the text in `tr-category` elements is the same as the text in `tr-title` elements.

```js
  function filterPosts(tag) {
            const postsList = document.querySelectorAll('.tr-item');
            let tagName = tag.children[0].innerText;
            tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

            if (tagName == 'all') {

                for (let i = 0; i < postsList.length; i++) {
                    let postTag = postsList[i].lastChild.previousSibling.innerText;
                    postTag = postTag.toLowerCase();

                    for (let i = 0; i < postsList.length; i++) {
                        postsList[i].classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                }

            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < postsList.length; i++) {
                    let postTag = postsList[i].lastChild.previousSibling.innerText;
                    postTag = postTag.toLowerCase();
                    if (postTag === tagName) {
                        postsList[i].classList.remove('hidden');
                    } else {
                        postsList[i].classList.add('hidden');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="tr-nav">
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts(this)">
            <div class="tr-title ">All</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts(this)">
            <div class="tr-title">Tag 1</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts(this)">
            <div class="tr-title">Tag 2</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="filterPosts(this)">
            <div class="tr-title ">Tag 3</div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tr-wrap">
        <div class="tr-list">
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <p>test</p>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <p>test</p>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <p>test</p>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <p>test</p>
                <div class="tr-category ">Tag 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr-item">
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5>
                <div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This almost works perfect, thanks! One issue I found was that if I do something like             <div class="tr-item"><div class="wrap"><h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h5><div class="tr-category">Tag 3</div></div></div> it will stop working. I'm unsure if the contents inside tr-item will change so is there a way to do this if we don't know how many children will be under tr-item? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I updated the solution for you, but be aware that just one more or less space can destroy your function